# Bash script: Avoid single quotes added to string

Tags: bash, git, escape-characters

I'm trying to get an output of one function and pass it to other.

```
set -x
OUTPUT=$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM develop... | sed 's/.*/"&"/')
./bin/phpcs $OUTPUT
```

My main problem is that the first function returns a list of files and files may contain spaces. So I'm wrapping them in double-quotes, but when I pass it to my other function other single quotes are added.

Output:

```
++ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM develop...
++ sed 's/.*/"&"/'
+ OUTPUT='"test file.php"
"testfile.php"'
+ ./bin/phpcs '"test' 'file.php"' '"testfile.php"'
```

Main end goal to have call equal to:

```
./bin/phpcs "test file.php" "testfile.php"
```

Comment: For more details, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: The result of an expansion (variable expansion like `$OUTPUT`, or command substitution) is data, and _not_ interpreted for shell syntax. If it would be, it would be impossible to deal with arbitrary input from a user. So the quotes you have in the variable are just regular characters when they come out of it, just like in every other programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are adding double quotes to the text outputted by `git diff`.  This mangles the pathnames and makes it even harder to correctly parse the file list, especially if any pathname happens to contain quotes.

The single quotes that you see in the tracing output is just added by `bash` to make it easier to see how strings are delimited (e.g. to show that `"test`, `file.php"`, and `"testfile.php"` are three separate arguments).  Remember that the tracing output of a shell is debugging output meant for giving you a hint of what the shell is doing, and is not generally the *actual* code run by the shell.

---

To safely use the pathnames that `git diff --name-only` outputs, consider also using the `-z` option.  This causes `git` to output the pathnames as a nul-delimited list.  You may then use `xargs -0` to execute any command on the elements of that list:

```bsh
git diff --name-only -z --diff-filter=AM develop... |
xargs -0 ./bin/phpcs
```

You could also read the list of files into an array.  For example, in the `bash` shell:

```bsh
readarray -d '' -t names < <( git diff --name-only -z --diff-filter=AM develop... )

./bin/phpcs "${names[@]}"
```

This obviously relies on `git diff` not outputting *too many names*.

Comment: Didn't realise `git diff` had a `-z` option. That makes it all much easier

Comment: @roaima Note that `-z` only has any effect with `--raw`, `--numstat`, `--name-only` or `--name-status` (see `man git-diff`).

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that your file names don't contain newlines you can use those to delimit your filenames and pop them into an array:

```
OIFS=$IFS IFS=$'\n'
files=( $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM develop...) )
IFS=$OIFS
```

Now you can interpolate the array as a list of quoted strings:

```
./bin/phpcs "${files[@]}"
```

This won't run on POSIX `sh` or `dash`. You need to use a shell such as `bash` that supports arrays

Answer (score 1):

No single quotes are added. `bash -x` just shows you which literal arguments are seen. As `$OUTPUT` is not quoted the word splitting acts on the spaces and newlines. The `"` are part of the variable and not relevant for the shell parsing.

You could do this:

```
eval ./bin/phpcs $OUTPUT
```

roaima's array approach seems better, though.